The Nachash and Bechira
How could the nachash in gan eden be punished if animals don’t have bechira (as is the implication of the Rambam Hil Teshuva 5:1, and Sanhedrin 108)?
Also, any sources would be great.
Thanks for your help

Not completely an answer, but refer to this Chasam Sofer.

I mean animals don’t speak either and yet…

Is this different from the trees/fruit and moon getting punished? The whole world is a reflection of Man and his relationship with Hashem.

The snake was punished, as a stumbling block reminder to humans for their sin. (Similar to the punishment of Bil'am's donkey). As a result of the corruption caused by the sin, dealing with the snake became unsurmountable barrier, Bereshit Rabba 20:5:
Rabbi Yudan and Rabbi Huna, one of them said: [God told the serpent:] ‘You caused people to walk bent over [in grief] over their dead…
At the same time, the gemara expresses regret for snake's punishment: the snakes could help humans at delivering parcels on long distances, Sanhedrin 59b:
As it is taught in a baraita that Rabbi Shimon ben Menasya says: Woe over a great attendant that has been lost to the world; as had the snake not been cursed that it should go on its belly, there would have been two fine snakes at the disposal of each and every one of the Jewish people. One he would send to the north, and the other one he would send to the south, to bring him precious sandalbonim, a type of precious stone, and other precious stones and pearls.
I.e. had Adam and Chava did not sin, the snake would turn out to be a great help in developing the world.
